# Prevent from adding row with same value within time window

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

For the sake of clarity lets assume I have table with 3 columns:

```
ID | Value | DateTimeInserted
```

Now I need to prevent row insertion with the same Value, if DateTimeInserted is less than 7 days for existing row with same Value.
Example:

```
ID | Value | DateTimeInserted
1  | AAA   | 2021-12-16
2  | BBB   | 2021-12-06
```

Expectation is that I can add row with GETUTCDATE() (=2021-12-17) for a row with Value = BBB, but database should prevent me from inserting Value = AAA and DateTimeInserted = 2021-12-17

So far I was considering:

- Filtered unique index - won't work as filter would be non-deterministic
- Indexed view showing only records from last 7 days - reason same as above
- I wrote a constraint that checks whether such row already exists, but I think it works in-memory and fails to prevent if I run queries in parallel (running simultaneously 10 inserts gives me between 5 and 10 rows inserted, when there should be only one)

Comment: Use a trigger here.

Comment: Trigger won't have same problem as constraint?

Comment: Your column name `DateTimeInserted` implies something very different from your discussion and sample data. Don't add confusion - always post actual DDL. More importantly post a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) so we don't have to guess. Don't just say you "considered" or "tried" something - post the code you actually wrote!

Comment: Does "Prevent from adding" mean ignore, e.g. with an `instead of` trigger, generate an error, e.g. with an `after` trigger, or simply take an exclusive lock on the table for 7 days?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your table is :

```
CREATE TABLE T (ID INT, A_VALUE CHAR(3), DateTimeInserted DATETIME2)

INSERT INTO T VALUES
(1, 'AAA', '2021-12-16'),
(2, 'BBB', '2021-12-06')
GO
```

The the trrigger would be :

```
CREATE TRIGGER E_IU
ON T
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
SET NOCOUNT ON;
IF NOT UPDATE(DateTimeInserted)
   RETURN;
IF EXISTS(SELECT *
          FROM   inserted AS i
                 JOIN T
                    ON i.A_VALUE = T.A_VALUE
                    AND i.DateTimeInserted BETWEEN T.DateTimeInserted 
                                           AND DATEADD(day, 7, T.DateTimeInserted))
BEGIN
   ROLLBACK;
   THROW 56789, 'Cannot insert a row with same value for A_VALUE when time period of 7 days is not ended', 1;

END;
GO
```

Comment: I think you need to add `AND i.ID <> T.ID` to make it work, see [db-fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=6be47ba6b7ba24942edadc59f4a3a70a)

Comment: @Turo yes, probably...